# Derivation needed

Tags: circuit-analysis, voltage-divider, passive-networks, delay, formula-derivation

I am using a chip that has the following circuit in it

[image]

where V_in is inputted on the left and V_out is measured on the right. This circuit is sometimes called the "lumped-element delay lines." I was told that the circuit can delay the input signal by a specified increment of time. In many books as well as websites, I see that the delay time from each element is calculated as

$$t_d = \sqrt{LC}$$

I have not seen any derivation for the expression above and would like to see the derivation. From the books, almost every author states something along the line of "it is trivial to derive the following...". However, I am having quite a difficult time deriving the above expression. I have tried to analyze the circuit by first looking at just one element and treat it as a voltage provider, which yield the following:

$$V_{out} = \frac{Z_C}{Z_L +Z_C}V_{in} = \frac{1}{1 - \omega^2LC}V_{in}$$

At this point, I am unsure how to proceed. From past experience, my guess is that the time delay must be the result of a phase shift, but I don't know how to go from what I currently have to a phase shift.

Note: It has been a long time since my last electronics class. So please provide as much detail as you can.

Comment: The expression you came up with is valid if there was only one stage. The additional stages change the equivalent impedance of capacitor branch and so you cannot use this equation (because you are wrongly assuming the capacitor branch unaffected by other stages)

Answer (score 1):

This is like a transmission line with no resistive components. If the capacitance and inductance per unit length is C and L respectivelely, then the propagation velocity is u = 1/sqrt(LC). Thus, the time required for a signal  to move a unit length to the right, is td = 1/u = sqrt(LC)

Answer (score 0):

The speed of light or the velocity of propagation of electricity is related to two constants: -

$$c = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon\cdot\mu}}$$

Where \$\epsilon\$ is the electric permittivity of the medium measured in farads per metre and \$\mu\$ is the magnetic permeability of the medium measured in henries per metre.

Given that you have a lumped model having L and C per length, it shouldn't be too hard to see that the speed formula can change to: -

$$c = \dfrac{distance}{\sqrt{LC}}$$

Then dividing both sides by distance turns c into the reciprocal of time hence the time delay is: -

$$t_d = \sqrt{LC}$$